# Console.CursorTop inside Notepad++ console

Tags: c#, console, notepad++

After finishing a basic console application, I wanted to run it through Notepad++ using the [NppExec extention](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/), but the app attempts to overwrite bits of the console with the output it produces.  Specifically, it does the following:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, (
  Console.CursorTop == 0 ? 0 :
    Console.CursorTop - (int)Math.Ceiling((input.Length + 1) / 80.0)
  )
);
```

That works fine for standard console windows, but when running through the NppExec console in Notepad++ it throws the following error:

> 'Console.CursorTop' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.IOException'
>   The handle is invalid.

For now, I bypass the cursor moving if the `Console.CursorTop` is not valid, which runs fine.  However, if there was a way to move the cursor inside the Notepad++ console, that would be perfect.  *Note that I'm not looking to just clear the entire console before writing the output.*

Is there a way to move the cursor in the Notepad++ console using a C# console app?  If not, is there a way to overwrite user input in the Notepad++ console via a C# console application?  I'd even accept simply returning the cursor to the beginning of the line before writing the output, if that's the best I could get.

Comment: Erm, Notepad++ does not have a console, last time I looked anyway.  So sure, members like CursorTop fail with an exception.  It is not clear why you try to use Console when there isn't one.

Comment: @HansPassant You are correct, it's from the [NPPExec](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/) extension.  I'll update the question to clarify that.